# imaplib - What is the correct folder name for Archive/All Mail in Gmail?

Tags: python, email, gmail, imaplib

I have a script which exports all the email in Gmail as text files.

It works fine with this line where you select the folder:

```
mail.select("inbox")
```

But I am not sure what the name is for Gmail's archive, where all of the email is stored. I've tried archive and all mail and stuff, but no luck.

Anyone know the correct name?

Comment: Can you interrogate the IMAP server to ask what folders ARE available? And does Google provide any documentation for their IMAP service? Alternately, if you connect to Gmail using a mail client, does archived mail show up in a folder at all?

Comment: @Li-aungYip - you can with the list() method. http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.list

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved it.

It is `[Gmail]/All Mail` or, if you are a Gmail UK user like me, it may be `[Google Mail]/All Mail`, because Gmail used to be called Google Mail in the UK due to trademark issues.

If you're doing this for general use, I'd recommend testing to see if `[Gmail]/All Mail` works (most common), and if not testing for `[Google Mail]/All Mail`.

The last one works perfectly for me.

Comment: For me you have to quote it: `'"[Gmail]/All Mail"'`

Answer (score 0):

This:

https://github.com/goerz/gmail_archive.py/blob/master/libgmail/lgconstants.py

Seems to indicate that it's `all`.

Comment: Hmm. all doesn't work. Gives error `command SEARCH illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states SELECTED`

Comment: Can we see the whole script? Can you paste it somewhere?