# Python imaplib recover emails with \\Deleted flag and move to trash

Tags: python, email, gmail, imaplib

I've been getting a lot of spam emails from various colleges. I wrote a simple Python program to go through my emails, and find all the ones whose sender ends in `.edu`.

Then, to delete it, I though I was supposed to add the `\\Deleted` flag to those emails using: `Gmail.store(id, "+FLAGS", "\\Deleted")`. This did not work, and some of them didn't even disappear from the inbox.

After more research, I found that instead I had to use `Gmail.store(id, "+X-GM-LABELS", "\\Trash")`.

So I updated the program to use that, but now it doesn't see any of the emails that I previously added the `\\Deleted` flag to.

Is there any way I can reset all those emails and then trash them afterward?

Comment: They should be in your All Mail folder.  Use the webui and search for them and trash them.

Comment: Oh, I see...what do I `Gmail.select` to get the "All Mail"?

Comment: In my python code

Comment: If it's a one off, why use Python?   Its locale specific, but in English it should be something like "[Gmail]/All Mail"

Comment: I'm using Python because there's 700 or so of them.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried that, but it gives me `SELECT command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']`

Comment: I'm also using Python because I'm going to probably keep receiving them for a while (I haven't unsubscribed from all of them yet), so I'll use it again another time.

Comment: Ok, the problem was addressed in this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186394/unable-to-retrieve-gmail-messages-from-any-folder-other-than-inbox-python3-issu

Comment: If you want to make an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I meant, why use a script for the one off clean-up, now that you know how to do it.  I've made an answer for you.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but I wanted to make sure I deleted those emails because I wanted to free up space on Gmail. A lot of them had image attachments and HTML.

Comment: Ah, what I meant i that future ones will be in your inbox, and you know how to deal with them properly.  Cleaning up the ones in your All Mail from your previous script is only something you need to do once.

Comment: Oh. Well again, since there was 700 of them, it would have taken me a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be in your All Mail folder. Use the WebUI and search for them and trash them, or select the `"[Gmail]\All Mail"` folder (watch out for localization, this can change name for non-English users).