# Querying All Emails in Gmail Inbox Using Python

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail, imap

I am using the following code to send and search emails in Gmail using Python,

```
import smtplib
import imaplib
import email
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import pandas as pd


class EmailClient:
    def __init__(self, email, password, smtp_server='smtp.gmail.com', smtp_port=587, imap_server="imap.gmail.com"):
    self.email = email
    self.password = password
    self.smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port)
    self.imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_server)

def send_email(self, to_addr, subject, body):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = self.email
    msg['To'] = to_addr
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    self.smtp_server.starttls()
    self.smtp_server.login(self.email, self.password)
    self.smtp_server.send_message(msg)
    self.smtp_server.quit()

def search_email(self, mailbox="INBOX", subject=None, to=None, from_=None, since_date=None, until_date=None,
                 since_emailid=None):

    self.imap_server.login(self.email, self.password)

    self.imap_server.select(mailbox)

    query_parts = []
    if subject is not None:
        query_parts.append(f'(SUBJECT "{subject}")')
    if to is not None:
        query_parts.append(f'(TO "{to}")')
    if from_ is not None:
        query_parts.append(f'(FROM "{from_}")')
    if since_date is not None:
        since_date_str = since_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
        query_parts.append(f'(SINCE "{since_date_str}")')
    if until_date is not None:
        until_date_str = until_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
        query_parts.append(f'(BEFORE "{until_date_str}")')
    if since_emailid is not None:
        query_parts.append(f'(UID {since_emailid}:*)')

    query = ' '.join(query_parts)

    ret = []

    resp, items = self.imap_server.uid('search', None, query)
    items = items[0].split()
    for emailid in items[::-1]:
        resp, data = self.imap_server.uid('fetch', emailid, "(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT TO FROM DATE)])")
        try:
            raw_email = data[0][1].decode("utf-8")
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            ValueError(f"Could not decode email with id {emailid}")
        email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)

        email_line = {}
        email_line['id'] = emailid
        email_line["to"] = email_message['To']
        email_line["from"] = email_message['From']
        email_line["subject"] = str(email_message['Subject'])
        email_line["created_at"] = email_message['Date']
        resp, email_data = self.imap_server.uid('fetch', emailid, '(BODY[TEXT])')
        email_line["body"] = email_data[0][1].decode('utf-8')

        ret.append(email_line)

    self.imap_server.logout()

    return pd.DataFrame(ret)
```

When I execute,

```
email_client = EmailClient('<email>',  '<app_password>')
email_client.search_email()
```

I expected all of the emails in my INBOX to be returned, instead I get the following error,

```
imaplib.IMAP4.error: UID command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']
```

What is the problem here?

I know that the same error has popped up here,

[Unable to retrieve gmail messages from any folder other than inbox (Python3 issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186394/unable-to-retrieve-gmail-messages-from-any-folder-other-than-inbox-python3-issu)

But, my issue seems to be a little different.

Another question along the same lines, is there a way for me to limit the number of results that are returned when running this function? Something similar to a `LIMIT` clause? How do I incorporate that to the query?

Comment: What is the actual command that causes the parse error?

Comment: The [ESEARCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4731)+[PARTIAL](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc9394/) extensions let you instruct the server to return fewer results. I haven't even tried to find out how many servers support PARTIAL.